# Get hourly updates using Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on an orders table which has fields order_id and order_completion_date. Order_completion_date shows  , when a specific order was completed. If the order is not completed then it will show a value like 4447-12-30 00:00:00.

My goal is to get number of records completed per hour within last 24 hours. I looked into other similar questions but could not find a way to represent the timestamp in following format:

```
       {
           "date_time":"07/05/2018 00:00:00", 
           "completed_orders":"1000" 
        },
        {
           "date_time":"07/05/2018 01:00:00",
           "completed_orders":"2000"
        },
        {
           "date_time":"07/05/2018 02:00:00",
           "completed_orders":"3000"
        },
        {
           "date_time":"07/05/2018 03:00:00",
           "completed_orders":"4000"
        },
        {
           "date_time":"07/05/2018 04:00:00",
           "completed_orders":"5000"
        }
```

I am trying following query right now:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(csg_order_id) AS completed_orders, hour(from_unixtime(cast(ord_completion_date as bigint))) as hour "
            + "FROM TotalTasks "
            + "WHERE ord_completion_date <= cast('"+curDate+"' as Timestamp) AND ord_completion_date >= date_add(cast('"+curDate+ "' as Timestamp), -1) "
            + "GROUP BY  hour "
            + "ORDER BY  hour");
```

but it is giving me results like this:

```
+----------------+----+
|completed_orders|hour|
+----------------+----+
|             143|   0|
|             336|   1|
|             570|   2|
|             649|   3|
|             297|   4|
|             219|   5|
|              68|   7|
|              52|   8|
|              56|   9|
|            7360|  10|
|              78|  12|
|              59|  19|
|             238|  21|
|             332|  22|
+----------------+----+
```

is there any way to get time instead of number of hours? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format) SQL function:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS completed,
  date_format(from_unixtime(bigint(ord_completion_date))), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00') AS date_time
 FROM tasks
 WHERE bigint(ord_completion_date) BETWEEN current_date AND date_add(current_date, 1)
 GROUP BY 2
 ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: but then it'll group by given date_time format and not hour. I want to group the records by hour for all ord_completion_date between past 24 hour.

Comment: There is no logical difference between grouping by hour and grouping by formatted dates. It can only affect performance.

Comment: but its giving 0 records.

Comment: ok then. Please, provide the schema of your input dataset and a couple of examples. To eliminate misunderstanding, so as to say.